# how to implement encryption library properly with salt in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, cryptography

Good day.

Using the encryption library in CodeIgniter, I can encrypt any string by using `$this->encryption->encrypt('string');` and that is the easiest way to encrypt the string. However, this method is not the safest way to secure the data I think so I decided to use salt for better encryption. I read the documentation provided by Codeigniter about the [Encryption Library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html) and I don't really understand how encryption and salt really work.

**Here is my code for encryption.**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MyEncryption {
    //please do not change or delete this saltKey. "5948356750394856"
    private static $saltKey = "5948356750394856";
    // ================
    public $CI;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('encryption');
    }

    public function encryptStringWithSalt($string) {
        $p = $this->CI->encryption->encrypt(
            $string,
            $this->encryption_config()
        );

        return $p;
    }

    public function decryptEncryptedStringWithSalt($encryptedString) {
        return $this->CI->encryption->decrypt(
            $encryptedString,
            $this->encryption_config()
        );
    }

    private function encryption_config(){
        $key = $this->CI->config->item('encryption_key');

        $hmac_key = $this->CI->encryption->hkdf(
        $key,
        'sha512',
        MyEncryption::$saltKey,
        10,
        'authentication'
        );

        return array(
            'cipher' => 'aes-128',
            'mode' => 'CTR',
            'key' => MyEncryption::$saltKey,
            'hmac' => true,
            'hmac_digest' => 'sha224',
            'hmac_key' => $hmac_key
        );
    }

}
```

As we can see, I created a function that gathers the encryption configuration. Inside that function, I have called the method `$this->CI->encryption->hkdf()` to create `hmac key` as what documentation example says. For clarification, here are the parameters of `hkdf()` method and the provided example. [image: screenshot1]

Additionally, the `return` keyword with `array data` in `encryption_config()` function is the 2nd parameter of `encrypt()` method in encryption library. I used `encryption->hkdf()` because of the parameter salt on it. I am new in encryption with salt in Codeigniter so I'm really struggling on how to achieve this kind of encryption. So what I've done is that the code above really works for encryption and decryption but for some reason I don't really understand why the return value is different from the normal encryption. The difference is, this encryption method `$this->encryption->encrypt("some string");` returns [image: normal encryption] but using the code above returns [image: salt encryption].

Though I can decrypt that symbolic character, this will not save this encrypted data to the database with the data type of varchar but instead, it will be saved as a normal character or string. Here are the data saved to database [image: db encrypt].

My questions are, I am doing correctly? if not, what is the proper way to implement this library with salt? I want the encrypted data as normal text not a symbolic character, can I achieve that goal?   and lastly? is there anyway to check the string if the string is encrypted or not? Please help me. I spend days for this problem only. I watch youtube tutorial related for encryption but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. after searching on the internet I found a solution without using this CI encryption Library. I achieved my goal by using this code

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * 
 */

class SaltEncryption
{
    public $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    
public function encrypt($data){
        $password = "any string";
        $iv = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 16);
        $password = sha1($password);

        $salt = sha1(mt_rand());
        $saltWithPassword = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);

        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt(
          "$data", 'aes-256-cbc', "$saltWithPassword", null, $iv
        );
        $msg_encrypted_bundle = "$iv:$salt:$encrypted";
        return $msg_encrypted_bundle;
    }


public function decrypt($msg_encrypted_bundle){
        $password = "any string";
        $password = sha1($password);

        $components = explode( ':', $msg_encrypted_bundle );
        if (
            count($components)=== 3 &&
            strlen($components[0]) === 16
        ) {

            $iv            = $components[0];
            $salt          = hash('sha256', $password.$components[1]);
            $encrypted_msg = $components[2];

            $decrypted_msg = openssl_decrypt(
              $encrypted_msg, 'aes-256-cbc', $salt, null, $iv
            );

            if ( $decrypted_msg === false )
                return false;

            $msg = substr( $decrypted_msg, 41 );
            return $decrypted_msg;

        }
        return false;

        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll let others point out the technical problems with this, but I will say that it's a bad idea to grab random security-critical code without knowing whether it's any good. There's a ton of garbage out there.